# Javascript convert decimal number into integer w/ comma formatting

Tags: javascript, string

We have a number like `23456.888` and want to display it rounded and with a comma as `23,457`. What we've tried:

```
23456.888.toFixed(0) // 23457
23456.888.toLocaleString('en-US') // 23,456.888
23456.888.toFixed(0).toLocaleString('en-US') // 23457
```

Comment: Call `toLocaleString` on the rounded number (not on the string, which isn't number-aware)

Comment: Math.round(23456.888, 0).toLocaleString('en-US'); works perfectly, thanks!